# Synchronizing on the same object twice

Tags: java, synchronization, thread-safety

I am writing a utility class to implement the behavior of a stopwatch. One important feature of this class is that it is designed to be thread-safe. I use a `private final` field called `lock` to synchronize on. Two of the methods in the class are called `reset` and `start`, which reset the stopwatch and start it, respectively. They are implemented as:

```
public void reset() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        beginTime = 0;
        lapIndex = 0;
    }
}

public void start() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        if (beginTime == 0) {
            beginTime = System.nanoTime();
            laps[lapIndex++] = beginTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Recently, I had the idea of adding an additional convenience method called `restart`, which would reset and the start the stopwatch. I want this to behave like an atomic operation, so my idea was to implement it as:

```
public void restart() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        reset();
        start();
    }
}
```

However, the `reset` and `start` methods already synchronize on `lock`, so invoking `restart` would synchronize on the same object two times. Could any problems arise from that? Is the behavior of synchronizing on the same object multiple times well-defined? Is it necessary? I have ran the code as it *seems* to work fine, but I fear I could be missing some subtleties as is common with multithreading.

Comment: Java uses reentrant locks, meaning you can synch on them more than once. Under the covers there's a counter of how many times a lock has been synched on, and when that counter goes back to zero (it gets decremented by 1 each time you exit a synchronized block of code ), the lock is released.

Answer (score 3):

There's no problem with synchronizing twice. The thread already owns the monitor so the extra synchronization doesn't really do much. This will be necessary, otherwise your `restart()` method might be interrupted by another thread between calls to `reset()` and `start()`.

A way of avoiding the double synchronization is to have `restart()`, `reset()`, and `start()` synchronize and then delegate to non-synchronized internal methods.

```
public void reset() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        _reset();
    }
}

public void start() {
    synchronized (lock) {
        _start();
    }
}

public void restart() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        _reset();
        _start();
    }
}

private void _reset() {
    beginTime = 0;
    lapIndex = 0;
}

private void _start() {
    if (beginTime == 0) {
        beginTime = System.nanoTime();
        laps[lapIndex++] = beginTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From [section 14.19 on `synchronized` statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.19) of the Java language specification:

> The locks acquired by synchronized statements are the same as the locks that are acquired implicitly by synchronized methods (§8.4.3.6). **A single thread may acquire a lock more than once.**

Also from the JLS:

> A thread *t* may lock a particular monitor multiple times; each unlock reverses the effect of one lock operation.

Therefore, this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Good quotes from the spec.